# expect freezes after send

Tags: bash, shell, expect, alpine-linux

I'm trying to automate a Alpine Linux installation using the following script:

```bsh
expect <<- EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn setup-disk -e -m sys /dev/sda
    expect {
        {WARNING: Erase the above disk(s) and continue? (y/n) \[n\] } {
            send "y\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3: " {
            send -- "helloworld\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Verify passphrase: " {
            send -- "helloworld\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    }
    expect eof
EOF
```

The problem is that whenever the script reaches the second prompt, it sends the password, but is unable to proceed any further, it just hangs without showing the next prompt

Comment: Without showing the input to this `expect` script, i.e. the output of the `setup-disk` command, with its prompts, it's a bit difficult to debug what's going wrong.

Comment: The script freezes on the second prompt, what comes before that is irrelevant, it displays: `Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3: helloworld`, goes to a new line, and just stops executing while the cursor keeps blinking on that empty line, looks like the `\r` is not being processed or something similar might be causing this

Comment: It's unusual that it displays the passphrase. I would have expected it to not echo the passphrase. I don't know `expect` much at all, but it might indicate that it's reading from the _terminal_ (rather than from standard input), or something like that. In any case, it's not actually getting the password you're sending it.

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` before you spawn. Then you'll be able to see what expect is waiting for. I suspect the prompt is not quite right (perhaps there's no trailing space)

Comment: @glennjackman after further inspection with `exp_internal 1`, the output tells that `Verify passphrase: ` is matching the `expect`, has the id `exp4` and is properly receiving the sent text, but still hangs the script

Comment: How long does `setup-disk` normally run for?

Comment: @glennjackman around half a minute, with this issue it's stopping in less than 10 seconds

Comment: Sounds to me like the expect script is working fine. Are you sure setup-disk is working correctly?

Comment: Yes, when i run it manually, it works fine, it's one of the official Alpine Linux installation scripts

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's no further interaction after "verify password", make a couple of small changes:

```
expect <<- EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn setup-disk -e -m sys /dev/sda
    expect {
        {WARNING: Erase the above disk(s) and continue? (y/n) \[n\] } {
            send "y\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3: " {
            send -- "helloworld\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Verify passphrase: " {
            send -- "helloworld\r"
            # removing `exp_continue`
            # the `expect` command then ends here
        }
    }
    # not `expect eof`, but
    interact
EOF
```

Now, you should be able to see what the spawned program is doing.

Comment: After making these changes (and including `exp_internal 1`), i've noticed that the script is matching the `"Verify passphrase: " prompt`, this same prompt received the `spawn_id` of `exp4`, and there's also this on the log: `spawn id exp4 sent <\r\n>` and `interact: received eof from spawn_id exp4`

Comment: Maybe highlight what changes were made and their significance, for people who don't want to go through the script line by line?

Comment: @glennjackman unfortunately, this solution is not working for me, the same error persists, but i found out that it's not actually freezing, it's just that everything after `"Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3"` is hidden for some reason (and can be made visible with `exp_internal 1`)